# How can I get the last 10 items in a list with REST API in ascending order?

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest

**example:** I have 10 items in a list. I want to display only 8, 9, and 10.

if I use `'&$top=10&$orderby=Created desc'`, it is giving me 10, 9 , and 8. if I use `'&$top=10&$orderby=Created asc'`..., it is giving me 1, 2, and 3.

any way around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ideally you can use multiple columns in `orderby` field. So in your case you can do something like

```
$top=10&$orderby=Created desc, Id asc
```

I tried above and for some reason it is not working. What you can do is once you receive the result read it from the end and come forward as below

```
success: function (data) {
    if (data.d.results.length > 0 ) {
        for(i = data.d.results.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            alert(data.d.results[i]);
        }
    }       
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`?$top=10&$orderby=Created desc,Id`
works like a charm